# Settings states before render - Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:
I would like to render out the `choice-main-div` as many times as the `problemcount` represents.

```js
class ChoiceTextBubble extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   

        this.state = {
                problemcount:3,
                renderArray:''
            }

        this.renderProblem();               
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.props.updateStoredContent(e);
    }

    renderProblem(){
        var tempArray=[];
        for (var i=0; i<this.state.problemcount;i++){
            tempArray.push(
            <div className="choice-main-div"> 
                <div className="mini-icon"> 
                    <img alt="mini-icon" src={exclam_icon}/>
                </div>
                <div className="choice-div">
                    <form>
                        <input onChange={ e => this.onChange(e)}  autocomplete="off" className ="nice-border normal" type="normal" name="input_problem 01" placeholder={this.props.desc[0]} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            )   
            console.log(tempArray);
        }
        this.setState({renderArray: tempArray});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="textbubble"> 
                <div className="form-section single">
                    <div className="title">
                        <h3>{this.props.title.toUpperCase()}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.renderArray}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ChoiceTextBubble;
```

However, I get the following warning:

*Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the ChoiceTextBubble component.*

I am trying to set the state of the renderArray - prior to rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the data to be rendered in state, you can directly call the function and render the result in render like below

```
class ChoiceTextBubble extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   

        this.state = {
                problemcount:3,
                renderArray:''
            }

    }

    onChange(e){
        this.props.updateStoredContent(e);
    }

    renderProblem(){
        var tempArray=[];
        for (var i=0; i<this.state.problemcount;i++){
            tempArray.push(
            <div className="choice-main-div"> 
                <div className="mini-icon"> 
                    <img alt="mini-icon" src={exclam_icon}/>
                </div>
                <div className="choice-div">
                    <form>
                        <input onChange={ e => this.onChange(e)}  autocomplete="off" className ="nice-border normal" type="normal" name="input_problem 01" placeholder={this.props.desc[0]} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            )   
            console.log(tempArray);
        }
       return tempArray;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="textbubble"> 
                <div className="form-section single">
                    <div className="title">
                        <h3>{this.props.title.toUpperCase()}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {this.renderProblem()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ChoiceTextBubble;
```

**P.S.** You were getting the warning because you were calling the renderProblem function in constructor which calls setState.